# Is there a way to change the default Access logo image in an Access form?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

When I create a form, Access automatically creates an "auto_logo" placeholder. I manually change its properties to the logo I want to use.

I think if I could change the default picture, new forms would appear with the logo I want to use.

Is this possible?

Thanks.
Armando.

Comment: You may want to follow the instructions here:  http://allenbrowne.com/ser-43.html  and specifically create a default database.